# Checking for duplicate words in a string in C

Tags: arrays, c, string

I have written a code in c to search for duplicate words in a string, It just appends every word in a string to a 2d string array, but it is returning 0 for the numbers of rows and duplicate strings, what is the problem with the code?

```c
int main() {
  char str[50] = "C code find duplicate string";
  char str2d[10][50];

  int count = 0;
  int row = 0, column = 0;

  for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    if (str[i] != '\0' || str[i] != ' ') {
      str2d[row][column] = str[i];
      column += 1;
    } else {
      str2d[row][column] = '\0';
      row += 1;
      column = 0;
    }
  }

  for (int x = 0; x <= row; x++) {
    for (int y = x + 1; y <= row; y++) {
      if (strcmp(str2d[x], str2d[y]) == 0 && (strcmp(str2d[y], "0") != 0)) {
        count += 1;
      }
    }
  }

  printf("%i %i", row, count);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: use this opportunity to learn using the debugger.

Comment: The condition `str[i] != '\0' || str[i] != ' '` will not work as you expect. Please learn about [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) for negating boolean expressions. By the way, `str[i] != '\0'` will always be true inside the loop, since that's handled by the loop condition.

Comment: Also the loop conditions `x <= row` and `y <= row` will be wrong. They will make the loops go out of bounds.

Comment: Lastly, what is the `strcmp(str2d[y], "0")` supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

The problems are:

1. `if (str[i] != '\0' || str[i] != ' ')` should be `if (str[i] != '\0' && str[i] != ' ')`. If I recall right, using the logical or will prevent reaching the `else` case.
2. `if (strcmp(str2d[x], str2d[y]) == 0 && (strcmp(str2d[y], "0") != 0))` should be `if (strcmp(str2d[x], str2d[y]) == 0)`. Otherwise, your code will not count duplicates when the word is `"0"`.
3. a. To avoid confusion, use something like `printf("Number of rows = %d, Number of duplicates = %d\n", row+1, count);`. Since C arrays start at index 0, that's what `row` in your code contains. But the number of rows is 1.

   b. If you haven't realised by now, there are no duplicates in your `str` variable: `char str[50] = "C code find duplicate string";`. So your code returns a correct value of 0. Change it to `char str[50] = "C code find duplicate duplicate";` (for example), your code will correctly return 1.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- the 2D array might be too small: there could be as many as 25 words in a 50 byte string, and even more if you consider sequences of spaces to embed empty words.
- the test `if (str[i] != '\0' || str[i] != ' ')` is always true.
- the last word in the string is not null terminated in the 2D array.
- the word at `str2d[row]` is uninitialized if the string ends with a space
- sequences of spaces cause empty words to be stored into the 2D array.
- there is no point in testing `strcmp(str2d[y], "0")`. This might be a failed attempt at ignoring empty words, which could be tested with `strcmp(str2d[y], "")`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char str[50] = "C code find duplicate string";
    char str2d[25][50];
    int count = 0, row = 0, column = 0;

    for (int i = 0;;) {
        // skip initial spaces
        while (str[i] == ' ')
            i++;
        if (str[i] == '\0')
            break;
        // copy characters up to the next space or the end of the string
        while (str[i] != ' ' && str[i] != '\0')
            str2d[row][column++] = str[i++];
        str2d[row][column] = '\0';
        row++;
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < row; x++) {
        for (int y = x + 1; y < row; y++) {
            if (strcmp(str2d[x], str2d[y]) == 0)
                count += 1;
        }
    }

    printf("%i %i\n", row, count);

    return 0;
}
```